# Ansible, how to call handler as whole play, not only one task

Tags: ansible

How to call handler myhandler.yml as whole play, not only one task from it ?

```
role
    --handlers
    ----myhandler.yml
    --tasks
    ----mytasks.yml
```

I have specific request, i can not use module for service handling, because, my app is running under nonroot account.

I have deploy tasks in tasks->mytasks.yml, but i want to trigger handler->myhandler.yml as notify handler.

There are a lot of nonstandart tasks in mytasks.yml: for example async call, check port, check pid, check process.

Is possible to run this handler as whole play as notify?

EDIT:
Or should i put myhandler.yml in tasks and call it through @include?

Answer (score -1):

Yes ..  Notify can be used to do so. 
No need to include handler file as handler.

In any task mention notify like you have handler for tomcat restart with name "restart tomcat" then any task which requires tomcat restart should have notify.

```
- name: Modify server.xml
  copy: 
   src: a.txt
   dest: server.xml
  notify: restart tomcat
```

This will automatically call handler at the end of playbook.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set to run handler at the end of task, regardless of outcome of the task, include in the task:

```
meta: flush_handlers
```